# How to send form data with react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-hook-form for the first time.I am trying to send the data back to my server but whenever I hit submit,I am unable to send data in first try.But if I submit again,the values are submitted successfully to my server.

<-- Here is my code -->

```
const RegisterUser = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    phoneNo: "",
  });
  const schema = yup.object().shape({
    firstname: yup.string().required("First name is required"),
    lastname: yup.string().required("Last name is required"),
    email: yup.string().required("Email is required"),
    password: yup.string().required("Password is required"),
  });
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur",
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });
const {email, password} = formData;
  const handleFormSubmit = async (data) => {
    setFormData({
      email: data.email,
      password: data.password
    });
const newUser = { email, password};
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      };
      const body = JSON.stringify(newUser);
      await axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/users`, body, config);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    // }
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleFormSubmit)}>
        <Input
          type="email"
          label="Email"
          name="email"
          ref={register}
          error={!!errors.email}
          helperText={errors?.email?.message}
        />

        <Input
          type="password"
          label="Password"
          name="password"
          ref={register}
          error={!!errors.password}
          helperText={errors?.password?.message}
        />
        <Button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form>
```

Comment: I think you don't need to use async function to set the data. Without async, it should work.

Comment: I am still unable to send data at first try even without async

Comment: @AnuragSharma did you ever figure this out?